# IBM i UNION *ALL used here

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have this in CL and would like to make it into a view. I first run 2 queries which are creating these 2 tables. How would the code here for the UNION ALL be? the 2 tables are (Logical) views

```
CPYF       FROMFILE(JETDTA/EODDETAILH) +                 
              TOFILE(JETDTA/EODDETAILS) MBROPT(*ADD) +    
              FMTOPT(*NOCHK)                                
              MONMSG CPF0000
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Why can't you use CREATE VIEW?

Comment: i can but i need to add the eoddetailh records to the eoddetails

Comment: Please clarify why `FMTOPT(*NOCHK)` is used. It implies a mismatch between the two files. If there is a mismatch, it will interfere with a UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the structure of the queries result must match, you can do it with:

```
CREATE VIEW yourViewName AS 
SELECT *
FROM JETDTA.EODDETAILH
UNION
SELECT *
FROM JETDTA.EODDETAILS
```

You can find more information about the CREATE VIEW command [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/html/as400/v4r5/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmsthcview.htm) and about the UNION clause [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/ssw_i5_54/sqlp/rbafykeyu.htm), both of those are part of SQL/400.

Comment: I ran this and it has an error 'Column list required.   ' i dont mind typing in the columns but would like to know if this can work with *

Comment: As I've mentioned, the structure of both results must match. I just made it using all columns (*) because I didn't know how are they composed. So, based on that message, you will have to specify the column list, something like `select fieldX AS result1,... UNION select fieldY as result1,...`